# How to know if object gets deleted in Python

Tags: python, pyside

I have an object in the heap and a reference to it. There are certain circumstances in which the object gets deleted but the reference that points to its location doesn't know that. How can I check if there is real data in the heap?

For example:

```
from PySide import *
a = QProgressBar()
b = QProgressBar()
self.setIndexWidget(index,a)
self.setIndexWidget(index,b)
```

Then the `a` object gets deleted but `print(a)` returns a valid address. However if you try `a.value()` - runtime error occurs (C++ object already deleted).

`a is None` returns `False`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `sip` module, read more about `sip` [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/python_api.html)

```
import sip

a = QProgressBar()
sip.isdeleted(a)
False

sip.delete(a)
a
<PyQt4.QtCore.QObject object at 0x017CCA98>

sip.isdeleted(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted
```

Comment: sip.isdeleted(a) returned True for me when an object was deleted, without raising any exception.

Comment: The output shown here is wrong: `sip.isdeleted(a)` will never raise that runtime error.

Comment: @ekhumoro It's a six year old answer, perhaps things have changed now. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Well, it was meant as hint to improve your answer ;-) (If `isdelete` ever did raise an exception, that would obviously have been a bug which has long since been fixed).

Answer (score 16):

For the [`PySide`](http://shiboken.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shibokenmodule.html) objects you'll need the `shiboken` module to perform object queries.  For `Pyside2`, you'll need [`shiboken2`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/shiboken2/shibokenmodule.html).

```
import shiboken  # shiboken2

print shiboken.isValid(a)
```

Comment: thx for your answer! but where can I find shiboken module? the pyside wiki is dead. I built pyside from source, and only found shiboken-python2.7.dll, but no shiboken pyd.

Comment: from Shiboken import shiboken should work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458572/shiboken-cannot-be-imported/25935614#25935614

Comment: Quick update, for `PySide2`, `shiboken2.isValid()` is available.

Comment: Or if using `Qt.py` - `QtCompat.isValid()`

Answer (score 0):

It is explicitly mentioned in the documentation when an object takes the responsibility for the deletion of another object. In your example, you can see this in the [Qt doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) :

> If index widget A is replaced with index widget B, index widget A will be deleted.