# Python, inconsistent results vs docs: object deleted but weak ref still 'active'

Tags: python, weak-references

There are many questions out there regarding this subject which I already checked. [Example dated 2014!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965642/14094460)

One can also find the 'canonical' documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref).

I don't know why I cannot reproduce the docs:

```
import weakref, gc
class A:
    pass
a = A()
b = weakref.ref(a)
a
Out[5]: <__main__.A at 0x250f782f3a0>
b()
Out[6]: <__main__.A at 0x250f782f3a0>
del a
b()
Out[8]: <__main__.A at 0x250f782f3a0>
gc.collect()
Out[9]: 9
b()
Out[10]: <__main__.A at 0x250f782f3a0>
```

`b` should be returning `None` but is not.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800372/python-delete-object-from-weak-reference) on which I am interested as well, remains unanswered since a couple of years as well. Just tagging in case somebody can address both in one shot.

(Windows 10, python 3.8, Conda env)

Comment: The REPL may have a reference to the object when you printed it.

Comment: But if I explicitly call `del` on `a`, should it be removed entirely? And `gc.collect()` is also explicitly called.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the environment you're using, but if those `Out[6]` and similar notations are referring to an actual list (that you can use to refer to previous outputs), then that's what's keeping your object alive.  `del` just removes a *name*, it doesn't affect the object at all unless that name was the last remaining reference to it.

Comment: @jasonharper I edited the question for better reading. I get what you mean. But then `gc.collect()` should have removed the data created by `a` entirely. The snippet I show is all I typed in a freshly new python REPL (conda env).

Comment: Your code works as expected if you put it in a file and run it with the `python` command, so there is no REPL involved.

Comment: Tks, got it and pasted it as an answer for future ref.

Comment: `del` does not delete objects. There is no way to manually delete an object in Python. `del a` unassigns the `a` variable.

Comment: That's ok. I was just not aware that the REPL is keeping the object alive even after calling `gc.collect()` since all var names pointing to `0x250f782f3a0` (in this case `a`) had been 'deleted' by me.

Comment: An ordinary Python REPL would not have kept the object alive after the `gc.collect()`, but not because of any garbage collection effects - the object would have died because the last reference to the `A` instance was the magic `_` variable, and after the `gc.collect()`, the return value from `gc.collect()` would be assigned to that variable.

Comment: This is yet another interesting info. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what was mentioned in the comments to the question and am posting an answer for documentation purposes. Running the said code in the REPL was the problem.

What I tried:

**test.py**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import weakref, gc
    class A: pass
    a = A()
    b = weakref.ref(a)
    print("a: ", a)
    print("b(): ", b())
    del a
    print("b(): ", b())
    gc.collect()
    print("b(): ", b())
```

`$ python test.py`:

```
a:  <__main__.A object at 0x000002678F96A400>
b():  <__main__.A object at 0x000002678F96A400>
b():  None
b():  None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it does work as documented.